# Reference of そのこと in the following passage

Tags: grammar

I can't figure out the reference of そのこと in the following passage. Does it means that この後の事態 is much more important than 成立しない会話? Or the opposite?

> リリス「お兄さんのことを、今も君は考えている？」
>
> ソフィア「・・・・・・・・・・・・」
>
> リリス「・・・・・・そう。待っているのね、彼のことを」
>
> 返答は、相変わらずの沈黙だ。 それに伴い、階下の騒ぎも聞こえない。
> 沈静したのか、それともこれは嵐の前か・・・・・・
>
> リリス「どちらだと思う？ストライフが来てくれたらいいのだけど、彼は彼で忙しそうだし・・・・・・」
>
> リリス「それでも待ってみましょうか。貴女は彼を、私は・・・・・・そうね、あの人を。待つ女っていうのも、それほど悪いものじゃないと思わない？」
>
> ソフィア「・・・・・・・・・・・・」
>
> 先ほどから成立しない会話を、しかしリリスは楽しんでいるようだった。少なくともそう、この後に事態はどう転ぶのか・・・・・・**そのこと**よりも重要だ。
>
> リリス「・・・・・・マスター、駒はそろいました。後は貴方にお任せします」
>
> どこか祈るようなリリスの声に、答えるものは・・・・・・

Master is not ソフィア, he doesn't even present in this scene.

Comment: I can't either. More contexts come before and after the passage might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is neither.

It is saying that the fact that 「リリスがその会話を**楽しんでいること**」 right this moment is more important than 「この後に事態はどう転ぶのかということ」.

Comment: Thank you. However, I just can't figure out why it is so. Could you please explain?

Comment: @DarkAkira The simplified version of the sentence is 「少なくとも、『この後に事態はどう転ぶのか』よりも重要だ」. The omitted subject of this sentence is what's written in the preceding sentence, and そのこと refers to what's written just before it.